# ASP.NET MVC route map

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, maproute, ignoreroute

Please help me to correct my ASP.NET MVC Route Map.

I've got a menu item with an ActionLink: 
`<li>@Html.ActionLink("Articles", "List", "Article")</li>`

On the Home page it looks like: 
`localhost/Article`  which is OK.

But on the concrete Article page with URL `localhost/Article/List/11` my menu link is the same:
`localhost/Article/List/11`

But I need `localhost/Article`

My route map code is as follows:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Article",
        url: "Article/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

Here is controller code:

```
public ActionResult List(int? id)
    {
        ArticlesDataManager artMgr = new ArticlesDataManager();
        ArticleViewModel art = new ArticleViewModel();

        art.Articles = artMgr.GetLastArticles();

        art.Article = (id == null) ? artMgr.GetLast() : artMgr.GetArticle((int)id);

        ViewData.Model = art;

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Do you need the id in the url?  Could you take that off the Article MapRoute.  Also you could try setting the RouteValueDictionary indicated by Shyju to new { id = null } instead of just new {}

Comment: Yes, I need Id in my url. article/list/id -show articles list and selected article. Article/list - show list of articles and last article by date. I know, that I can resolve my problem by adding new action like "view". Article/view/id. But I am interested to use only one action:)

Comment: Is the int a Nullable int into your controller action i.e. int? id.  Perhaps this might also have an effect combined with the new { id = null } of the ActionLink() method

Comment: @dreza Yes, I adde my controller code into the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my problem was solved by changing my route map:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "ArticleByFirst",
               url: "Article/{action}/",
               defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "List" }
           );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ArticleById",
                url: "Article/List/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

And my menu-link looks like:  `<li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ArticleByFirst", new { action = "List" })">Articles</a></li>`

And my item-link is: `<li><a href="@Url.RouteUrl("ArticleById", new { id = item.Id })">@item.Name</a></li>`

It's not good, that I can't choose name of Route Map in ActionLink.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your current querystrings items are being added to your action link. To avoid this problem,   Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd493068%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) overload and try to explicitly pass `null` as RouteValues and see what changes it brings.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    RouteValueDictionary routeValues,
    IDictionary<string, Object> htmlAttributes
)
```

So your code can be re-written as

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Articles", "List", "Article",
                                        new RouteValueDictionary { },null)</li>
```

You can also try this version also

```
<a href="Url.Action("List", "Articles")">Articles</a>
```

Comment: in this case url of menu is /Home/List?Length=7

Comment: @YuriyMayorov: Sorry.It was a wrong overload. Try the updated one.

Comment: can u share a sample project ?  on skydrive ?